# Read html format from mail body

Tags: c#

I am reading the mail body using streamReader with ASCII encoding type but the text received is in plain text format. It also contains some special characters like =92,=93,=94,=20 etc which does not resemble to html endoding. Also hyperlinks are converted to text like www.google.com http://www.google.com/

I debug the stream.getline function and find these lines containing content-Type, the first and second lines are before and after subject and third one is just before body of mail. Neither of three contains text/html. 
Please advice what to do.

```
1. Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=0015174479b83c0db404b1bf7ace
2. Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=0015174479b83c0db104b1bf7acd
3. Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Also please find the mail which I am reading:

**Spammy title:**
Spammy Body
Go to {spammy hyperlink}

The data in streamReader in get is:
*Spammy title:*** Spammy Body Go to spammydomain  *

I don't know why the * is attached at begining and end of every bold word/sentence and link is not treated as link. 
also while debuging other mails I found that some characters are also replaced, here is the list I found.

```
"=85" replaces "..."   on every occurance
"=93"replaces "\""     on every occurance
"=94"replaces "\""     on every occurance
"=92" replaces "'"      on every occurance
"****\r\n" replaces "\n"   randomly
"=\r\n" replaces ""         randomly
"=20\r" replaces ""        randomly
```

I tried Html Encoding / Decoding but nothing successfull.

Can you please suggest any encoding type or method to remove all the special characters and retain its html format.

Comment: If this is a real question, your choice in e-mails to debug is questionable.  It *makes this question look like disguised spam to me*

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham - Sorry if this question look like disguised spam to you, but it's not a spam. I wrote what i found, I described what mail I get and after getting the mail body in string what was the result. I also described which characters are converted into which. I also found that the problem is the body is encrypted to MIME2822 format and I don't know how to decrypt it to ASCII or simple text format. Can you please suggest.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham hi, can you please tell which encoding type this site is using to post users comments. As it's encoding type is resembling mine. It also uses * before and after bold char/words and this is not html encoding. Please advice.

Comment: Encoding type?  This site?  Check: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should start digging in some RFCs. I suggest:

RFC 822, *"STANDARD FOR THE FORMAT OF ARPA INTERNET TEXT MESSAGES"*,  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822

RFC 2047, *"MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) Part Three Message Header Extensions for Non-ASCII Text"*, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047, and especially the 4.2. section about "The "Q" encoding" which I believe should details the "special characters" like =92, =93, etc...

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, My streamreader data is encoded in RFC2822, but I don't know how to decode it back to ASCII or normal string which I can display on the radeditor or textarea. Can you please help me.